# Did I do this UML Diagram Properly?

Tags: java, uml

Problem: Did I properly make this UML Diagram?

UML Diagram:

Circle

- -radius : double
- +PI : double
- +setRadius(rad: double) : void
- +getRadius(rad: double) : void
- +getArea() : double
- +getDiameter() : double
- +getCircumference() : double

Code:

```
 public class Circle
{

  //Declaration
  private double radius;
  public static final double PI = 3.14159; 


  public Circle()
 {
  radius = 0.0;
 }
    public Circle(double rad)
   {
       radius = rad;
     }

   /**
     The setRadius method stores a value in the
     radius field.
      @param rad The value to store in radius.
   */

  public void setRadius(double rad)
   {
      radius = rad;
  }
    /**
     The getRadius method returns a Radius
     for the Circle.
     @return The entered radius in the radius field.
   */
    public double getRadius(double rad)
    {
  return radius;
   }
    /**
     The getArea method returns an Area
    for the Circle.
     @return The Area for the Circle.
   */
   public double getArea()
   {
     return PI * (radius * radius);
   }
     /**
     The getDiameter method returns a diameter
     for the Circle.
     @return The diameter for the Circle.
   */
```

Comment: whats happened to +getDiameter() : double and +getCircumference() : double

Comment: I think also that you have to underline PI as it is a static (i.e a class attribute).